# Find the positive divisors!

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, restricted-source, number-theory, restricted-complexity

## Definition

A number is positive if it is greater than zero.

A number (`A`) is the divisor of another number (`B`) if `A` can divide `B` with no remainder.

For example, `2` is a divisor of `6` because `2` can divide `6` with no remainder.

## Goal

Your task is to write a program/function that takes a positive number and then find all of its divisors.

## Restriction

- You may not use any built-in related to *prime* **or** *factorization*.
- The complexity of your algorithm must **not exceed O(sqrt(n))**.

## Freedom

- The output list may contain duplicates.
- The output list does not need to be sorted.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes wins.

## Testcases

```
input    output
1        1
2        1,2
6        1,2,3,6
9        1,3,9
```

Comment: You probably mean *divisor*, not *factor*. And I guess you want to have a *time complexity* of `O(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: What is the difference between *divisor* and *factor*?

Comment: We talk about factors of e.g. a number, if the product of these results in the original number again, but the divisors are usually the numbers that *divide* said number without remainder.

Comment: @flawr Updated accordingly.

Comment: I suppose built-ins for divisors themselves are also disallowed. :P (Might want mention that explicitly.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner As long as their complexity does not exceed O(sqrt(n)).

Comment: Should have more examples. `99 (1 3 9 11 33 99)`

Answer (score 4):

## PostgreSQL, 176 bytes

```
WITH c AS(SELECT * FROM(SELECT 6v)t,generate_series(1,sqrt(v)::int)s(r)WHERE v%r=0)
SELECT string_agg(r::text,',' ORDER BY r)
FROM(SELECT r FROM c UNION SELECT v/r FROM c)s
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8206/0)**</kbd>

Input:  `(SELECT ...v)`

How it works:

- `(SELECT ...v)` - input
- `generate_series(1, sqrt(v)::int)` - numbers from 1 to sqrt(n)
- `WHERE v%r=0` -filter divisors
- wrap with common table expression to refer twice
- `SELECT r FROM c UNION SELECT v/r FROM c` generete rest of divisors and combine
- `SELECT string_agg(r::text,',' ORDER BY r)` produce final comma separated result

---

Input as table:

```
WITH c AS(SELECT * FROM i,generate_series(1,sqrt(v)::int)s(r)WHERE v%r=0)
SELECT v,string_agg(r::text,',' ORDER BY r)
FROM(SELECT v,r FROM c UNION SELECT v,v/r FROM c)s
GROUP BY v
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56100/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦════════════════╗
║ v   ║   string_agg   ║
╠═════╬════════════════╣
║  1  ║ 1              ║
║  2  ║ 1,2            ║
║  6  ║ 1,2,3,6        ║
║  9  ║ 1,3,9          ║
║ 99  ║ 1,3,9,11,33,99 ║
╚═════╩════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 3):

## C#6, 75 bytes

```
string f(int r,int i=1)=>i*i>r?"":r%i==0?$"{i},{n(r,i+1)}{r/i},":n(r,i+1);
```

Based on the C# solution of downrep_nation, but recursive and golfed further down utilizing some new features from C#6.

Basic algorithm is the same as the one presented by downrep_nation. The for-loop is turned to a recursion, thus the second parameter. recursion start is done by the default parameter, thus the function is called with the required single starting-number alone.

- using expression based functions without a block avoids the return statement
- string interpolation within ternary operator allows to join string concatenation and conditions

As most answers here (yet) do not follow the exact output format from the examples, I keep it as it is, but as a drawback the function includes a single trailing comma at the result.

Comment: Nice first post!

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>36</s> 31 bytes

```r
n=scan();c(d<-1:n^.5,n/d)^!n%%d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTOlkjxUbX0CovTs9UJ08/RTNOMU9VNeW/peV/AA)

-5 bytes thanks to [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder)

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTOlkjxUbX0CovTs9UJ08/RTNaMU9VNSX2v6HZfwA "R – Try It Online") with `n^.5` instead of `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: You can go down to [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTOlkjxUbX0CovTs9UJ08/RTNOMU9VNeW/peV/AA "R – Try It Online") by duplicating the `1` many times.

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, 48 bytes

```
n=input('');a=1:n^.5;b=mod(n,a)<1;[a(b),n./a(b)]
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: Also, you devised an algorithm that I could not think of... How stupid I am.

Comment: I find all the divisos up to `sqrt(n)` and then put  each divisor `d` and `n/d` in my list.

Comment: Added some rules. Maybe could save you some bytes.

Comment: Indeed, I can omit `unique` now. Please note that changing the rules after people submitted answers it is usually frowned upon, consider using the Sandbox for future challenges!

Comment: I usually notify people if I change the rules to cause less harm.

Comment: What does `./` do?

Comment: `./` is entry-wise division. (`n` is a scalar, `a(b)` is an matrix)

Comment: I haven't tested, but can't you use `b=~mod(n,a)` to save 1 byte?

Answer (score 2):

## J, 26 bytes

```
(],%)1+[:I.0=]|~1+i.@<.@%:
```

### Explanation

```
(],%)1+[:I.0=]|~1+i.@<.@%:  Input: n
                        %:  Sqrt(n)
                     <.@    Floor(Sqrt(n))
                  i.@       Get the range from 0 to Floor(Sqrt(n)), exclusive
                1+          Add 1 to each
             ]              Get n
              |~            Get the modulo of each in the range by n
           0=               Which values are equal to 0 (divisible by n), 1 if true else 0
       [:I.                 Get the indices of ones
     1+                     Add one to each to get the divisors of n less than sqrt(n)
   %                        Divide n by each divisor
 ]                          Get the divisors
  ,                         Concatenate them and return
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) - 48 bytes

```
f=n=>[...Array(n+1).keys()].filter(x=>x&&!(n%x))
```

Not very efficient but works! Example below:

```js
let f=n=>[...Array(n+1).keys()].filter(x=>x&&!(n%x));
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.querySelector("output").value = f(Number(this.value)).join(", ");
});
```

```html
Divisors of <input type="number" min=0 step=1> are: <output></output>
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: This is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ and as such is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

Code:

```
ÐtLDŠÖÏDŠ/ï«
```

Explanation:

```
Ð             # Triplicate input.
 tL           # Push the list [1, ..., sqrt(input)].
   D          # Duplicate that list.
    Š         # Pop a,b,c and push c,a,b.
     Ö        # Check for each if a % b == 0.
      Ï       # Only keep the truthy elements.
       D      # Duplicate the list.
        Š     # Pop a,b,c and push c,a,b
         /ï   # Integer divide
           «  # Concatenate to the initial array and implicitly print.
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RHRMwqnDlsKuc8OPRMK5cy_Dr8Kr&input=Ng).

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
tX^:\~ftGw/h
```

The approach is similar to that in [@flawr's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78984/36398).

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFheOlx-ZnRHdy9o&input=Ng)

#### Explanation

```
t      % take input N. Duplicate.
X^:    % Generate range from 1 to sqrt(N)
\      % modulo (remainder of division)
~f     % indices of zero values: array of divisors up to sqrt(N)
tGw/   % element-wise divide input by those divisors, to produce rest of divisors
h      % concatenate both arrays horizontally
```

Comment: I do often wonder whether the combinded code of programs written in MATL would make a good RNG.

Comment: @flawr That probably applies to pretty every code golf language :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 64 bytes

```py
lambda n:sum([[x,n/x]for x in range(1,int(n**.5+1))if n%x<1],[])
```

This anonymous function outputs a list of divisors. The divisors are computed by trial division of integers in the range `[1, ceil(sqrt(n))]`, which is `O(sqrt(n))`. If `n % x == 0` (equivalent to `n%x<1`), then both `x` and `n/x` are divisors of `n`.

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/rzMwmj)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
½Rḍ³Tµ³:;
```

As the other answers, this is **O(√n)** if we make the (false) assumption that integer division is **O(1)**.

#### How it works

```
½Rḍ³Tµ³:;  Main link. Argument: n

½          Compute the square root of n.
 R         Construct the range from 1 to the square root.
  ḍ³       Test each integer of that range for divisibility by n.
    T      Get the indices of truthy elements.
     µ     Begin a new, monadic chain. Argument: A (list of divisors)
      ³:   Divide n by each divisor.
        ;  Concatenate the quotients with A.
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wr1S4biNwrNUwrXCszo7&input=&args=OQ)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39162/discussion-between-dennis-and-kenny-lau).

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 47 bytes

```js
d=(n,f=1,s='')=>n==f?s+n:d(n,f+1,n%f?s:s+f+',')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 50 bytes

Similar to @flawr's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78982/find-the-positive-divisors/78984#78984).

Performs trail division for *x* from 1 up to the square root of *n* and if divisible, saves it to a list as *x* and *n* / *x*.

```
(#2/#)~Join~#&@@{Cases[Range@Sqrt@#,x_/;x∣#],#}&
```

- Note that `∣` requires 3 bytes to represent in UTF-8, making the 48 character string require 50 bytes in UTF-8 representation.

### Usage

```
  f = (#2/#)~Join~#&@@{Cases[Range@Sqrt@#,x_/;x∣#],#}&
  f[1]
{1, 1}
  f[2]
{2, 1}
  f[6]
{6, 3, 1, 2}
  f[9]
{9, 3, 1, 3}
```

Comment: Well, it requires 3 bytes...

Comment: @KennyLau Yes, I was wrong, should have double-checked

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>66</s> 62 bytes

```
f=(n,d=1)=>d*d>n?[]:d*d-n?n%d?f(n,d+1):[d,...f(n,d+1),n/d]:[d]
```

I thought I'd write a version that returned a sorted deduplicated list, and it actually turned out to be 4 bytes shorter...

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 87 bytes

---

**Golfed**

```cs
String m(int v){var o="1";int i=1;while(++i<=v/2)if(v%i==0)o+=","+i;o+=","+v;return o;}
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```cs
String m( Int32 v ) {
    String o = "1";
    Int32 i = 1;

    while (++i <= v / 2)
        if (v % i == 0)
            o += "," + i;

    o += "," + v;

    return o;
}
```

---

**Full code**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace N {
    class P {
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            List<Int32> li = new List<Int32>() {
                1, 2, 6, 9,
            };

            foreach (Int32 i in li) {
                Console.WriteLine( i + " »> " + m( i ) );
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static String m( Int32 v ) {
            String o = "1";
            Int32 i = 1;

            while (++i <= v / 2)
                if (v % i == 0)
                    o += "," + i;

            o += "," + v;

            return o;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Releases**

- **v1.0** - `87 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

**Notes**

- In the **Golfed code**, I use `var`'s and `int`'s instead of `String`'s and `Int32`'s to make the code shorter, while in the **Ungolfed Code** and **Full Code** I use `String`'s and `Int32`'s to make the code more readable.

Comment: I've heard that `for` is generally better than `while`.

Comment: Your solution has a complexity of O(n) instead of O(sqrt(n))...

Comment: @KennyLau it depends of the situation, in this case having a `for` loop would have the same length that the `while` loop has. In this case it is irrelevant having on or the having the other.

Comment: But in this case it can save you a byte...

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 83 bytes

```
s=''x=io.read()for i=1,x do if x%i==0 then s=s..i..', 'end end print(s:sub(1,#s-2))
```

I couldn't do better, unfortunately

Comment: 1. welcome to PPCG, hope you'll enjoy this site! 2. you can change ==0 to <1 to save some bytes. 3. you can use the ternary structure instead of if then end, but i don't know if it wil save any bytes. 4. your algorithm's complexity is O(n) which does not meet the requirement.

Comment: All right. Does the list need to be ordered, or formatted appropriately?

Comment: "
    The output list may contain duplicates.
    The output list does not need to be sorted.
"

Comment: Right lol. And do I need to print the result or an array containing it is enough?

Comment: Well, either you print it or you return it (inside a function).

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 40 bytes

```perl6
{|(my@a=grep $_%%*,^.sqrt+1),|($_ X/@a)}
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{
  # this block has an implicit parameter named $_

  # slip this list into outer list:
  |(

    my @a = grep
                 # Whatever lambda:
                 # checks if the block's parameter ($_)
                 # is divisible by (%%) this lambda's parameter (*)

                 $_ %% *,

                 # upto and exclude the sqrt of the argument
                 # then shift the Range up by one
                 ^.sqrt+1
                 # (0 ..^ $_.sqrt) + 1

                 # would be clearer if written as:
                 # 1 .. $_.sqrt+1
  ),
  # slip this list into outer list
  |(

    # take the argument and divide it by each value in @a
    $_ X/ @a

    # should use X[div] instead of X[/] so that it would return
    # Ints instead of Rats
  )
}
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
my &divisors = {|(my@a=grep $_%%*,^.sqrt+1),|($_ X/@a)}

.say for (1,2,6,9,10,50,99)».&divisors
```

```
(1 1)
(1 2 2 1)
(1 2 3 6 3 2)
(1 3 9 3)
(1 2 10 5)
(1 2 5 50 25 10)
(1 3 9 99 33 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

### c#, 87 bytes

```
void f(int r){for(int i=1;i<=Math.Sqrt(r);i++){if(r%i==0)Console.WriteLine(i+" "+r/i);}
```

i do not know if this works for all numbers, i suspect it does.

but the complexity is right, so thats already something isnt it

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 56 bytes

```
->n{a=[];(1..Math.sqrt(n)).map{|e|a<<e<<n/e if n%e<1};a}
```

Answer (score 0):

## IA-32 machine code, 27 bytes

Hexdump:

```
60 33 db 8b f9 33 c0 92 43 50 f7 f3 85 d2 75 04
ab 93 ab 93 3b c3 5a 77 ec 61 c3
```

Source code (MS Visual Studio syntax):

```
    pushad;
    xor ebx, ebx;
    mov edi, ecx;
myloop:
    xor eax, eax;
    xchg eax, edx;
    inc ebx;
    push eax;
    div ebx;
    test edx, edx;
    jnz skip_output;
    stosd;
    xchg eax, ebx;
    stosd;
    xchg eax, ebx;
skip_output:
    cmp eax, ebx;
    pop edx;
    ja myloop;
    popad;
    ret;
```

First parameter (`ecx`) is a pointer to output, second parameter (`edx`) is the number. It doesn't mark the end of output in any way; one should prefill the output array with zeros to find the end of the list.

A full C++ program that uses this code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
__declspec(naked) void _fastcall doit(uint32_t* d, uint32_t n) {
    _asm {
        pushad;
        xor ebx, ebx;
        mov edi, ecx;
    myloop:
        xor eax, eax;
        xchg eax, edx;
        inc ebx;
        push eax;
        div ebx;
        test edx, edx;
        jnz skip_output;
        stosd;
        xchg eax, ebx;
        stosd;
        xchg eax, ebx;
    skip_output:
        cmp eax, ebx;
        pop edx;
        ja myloop;
        popad;
        ret;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    uint32_t n;
    std::stringstream(argv[1]) >> n;
    std::vector<uint32_t> list(2 * sqrt(n) + 3); // c++ initializes with zeros
    doit(list.data(), n);
    for (auto i = list.begin(); *i; ++i)
        std::cout << *i << '\n';
}
```

The output has some glitches, even though it follows the spec (no need for sorting; no need for uniqueness).

---

Input: 69

Output:

```
69
1
23
3
```

The divisors are in pairs.

---

Input: 100

Output:

```
100
1
50
2
25
4
20
5
10
10
```

For perfect squares, the last divisor is output twice (it's a pair with itself).

---

Input: 30

Output:

```
30
1
15
2
10
3
6
5
5
6
```

If the input is close to a perfect square, the last pair is output twice. It's because of the order of checks in the loop: first, it checks for "remainder = 0" and outputs, and only then it checks for "quotient < divisor" to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 49 bytes

```
INPUT N
FOR D=1TO N/D
IF N MOD D<1THEN?D,N/D
NEXT
```

Uses the fact that `D>N/D` = `D>sqrt(N)` for positive numbers

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>87</s> 81 bytes

Improved by [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat), 81 bytes:

```c
i,j;main(n,b)int**b;{for(;j=sqrt(n=atoi(b[1]))/++i;n%i||printf("%u,%u,",i,n/i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoQwDADAvwhCohHx4iX4kmUPbaES0ai1ntSvb1aY44RmDMFMaOLFiYKSR9FcVZ6vuCbgaTj2lEEHl1cB/@m@iG1dC2sp972lN0coypNeBQlpK4j8mFn/C3F242HNvPwB)

---

My original answer, 87 bytes:

```c
i;main(int n,char**b){n=atoi(b[1]);for(;(int)sqrt(n)/++i;n%i?:printf("%u,%u,",i,n/i));}
```

Compile with `gcc div.c -o div -lm`, and run with `./div <n>`.

---

*Bonus:* An even shorter variant with O(n) time complexity and hardcoded `n` (46 bytes + length of `n`):

```c
i,n=/*INSERT VALUE HERE*/;main(){for(;n/++i;n%i?:printf("%u,",i));}
```

---

*Edit: Thank you to @Sriotchilism O'Zaic for pointing out that inputs should not be hardcoded, I modified the main submission to take the input via argv.*

Comment: Is `n` the input?  Putting the input in a variable is not an accepted way of doing input here for a number of reasons.  You can see more about our accepted and non-accepted input and output forms here: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods.  And if you are curious about a specific language (e.g. C) you can look here: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/new-users-guides-to-golfing-rules-in-specific-languages.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic Yes, `n` is the input. I'll try modifying it so it takes the input some other way. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 22 chars, 44 bytes

```
{v∪⍵÷v←k/⍨0=⍵∣⍨k←⍳⌊√⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{v∪⍵÷v←k/⍨0=⍵∣⍨k←⍳⌊√⍵}
  f 1
1 
  f 2
1 2 
  f 6
1 2 6 3 
  f 9
1 3 9 
  f 90
1 2 3 5 6 9 90 45 30 18 15 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 40 bytes

Just providing an updated C# answer

```cs
n=>Enumerable.Range(1,n).Where(x=>n%x<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXouPpmleam1qUmJSTCuLb2SmkKdj@z7O1Q4jrBSXmpadqGOrkaeqFZ6QWpWpU2NrlqVbYGGr@t@YKL8osSfXJzEvVKC4pysxL1/PKz8zTUNJR0lFI0zDU1NQkoMSIsBIzwkosQUr@AwA)